# Number of binary words with a length of $n$, with $m$ 1s and at least $k$ 0s between 1s

Tags: combinatorics

The problem is to find the number of binary words of length of $n$, with $m$ 1s and at least $k$ 0s between 1s.

I have been thinking about this for a few days now, but I am unable to simplify it thus far.

I tried to determine the positions of the first and last 1s, but that led me to a similar problem (although on a smaller scale, so perhaps this is a correct approach).

However I believe that there is a simpler approach. Could anyone provide some guidance?

EDIT: Maybe I should consider the 100... as a single unit, this makes it a lot simpler. Is it correct though?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to reword it as such:

1. construct the word $100\cdots 010\cdots 010\cdots1$ where you have $m$ ones, and $k$ zeroes between each of the ones.
2. Now, you have some number, call it $x$ of zeroes left. You can insert them into any one of the gaps between the ones, or at the start, or at the finish, that is, you can place any zero at one of $m+1$ options.
3. Notice that the order at which you place the zeroes is not important.